# Issue with counting of observations in R using dplyr verbs: group_by and reframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Consider below `df`:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Gender, ~Condition, ~var1, ~var2, 
  "Bangladesh", "Male", "Rural", 1, 2.3,
  "Bangladesh", "Female", "Urban", 0, 6.2,
  "Bangladesh", "Male", "Rural", 1, 3.9,
  "Bangladesh", "Male", "Urban", 0, 4.2,
  "Laos", "Female", "Rural", 0, 1.5,  
  "Laos", "Female", "Rural", 0, 6.7,
  "Laos", "Female", "Rural", 0, 5,
  "Laos", "Male", "Urban", 1, 7.8,
  "Laos", "Male", "Urban", 1, 0.8,
  "China", "Male", "Urban", 0, 1.9, 
  "China", "Male", "Urban", 1, 6.7,
  "China", "Male", "Urban", 1, 8.5,
  "China", "Female","Urban", 1, 6,
  "China", "Female", "Urban", 1, 3.2,
  "China", "Female", "Rural", 0, 7.1
)
```

I use the below syntax to retrieve the number of observations in each category:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Gender = "All") %>%
  bind_rows(., df) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(Gender, Condition), values_to = "subgroup") %>%
  pivot_longer(c(var1, var2), names_to = "Variables", values_to = "Values") %>%
  group_by(Country, subgroup, Variables)%>%
  reframe(n= n())%>%
  print(n = 50)
```

Could someone help me understand why count numbers for `rural` and `urban` are returned twice the size of their real values. For instance, in `df` there are 5 urban observation, and 1 rural for China. However, the syntax return 10 and 2, respectively.

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: You double the observations by row binding the data with itself - `bind_rows(., df)`.  What are you trying to achieve with this step?

Comment: I need to have `all`, `male`, `female`, `urban`, `rural` categories seperately in my code.

Comment: Create the `"all"` variable separately (i.e. don't overwrite `Gender`) and include the new variable in the first pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? I am not sure I understood what you want.

```
df1<-reshape2::melt(df, id.vars=c("Country", "var1","var2"), measure.vars=c("Gender", "Condition"))
df1
```